# How to manage in cakephp a route with regex having a particular suffix

Tags: cakephp, routes

Searched here but didn't find.
I need to redirect all urls to a controller matching by condition.
http://www.example.com/thearticlename_q_12
if the suffix appears *q* (surrounded by 2 underscores) to redirect to my controller.
How i can solve?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried changing the regex of a parameter when routing ([docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action))? If not, what have you tried? And what are your routes?

Comment: I didn't find any solution sorry, also documentation I didn't find. I did in htaccess this but i prefer to in the router. RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+_s_([0-9]+)$ showstory.php?id=$1

Comment: that you posted in documentation refers to www.example.com/blog/thearticlename ... but I need to have without other words inside.

Comment: Please add destination url also that means Source is like http://www.example.com/thearticlename_q_12, what be the destination url?

Comment: destination url could be any controller, i need simply to catch a request with url inside _q_ and to be redirect to any controller, this for seo reasons of course. i could to redirect any request to a controller and parse, but to me seems not a nice solution ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:id',
    array(
        'controller' => 'MyController',
        'action' => 'my_action'
    ),
    array("id" => "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+_q_([0-9]+)")
);
```

Comment: Now if anyone can tell me how to match any file with the suffix .less.css, with a variable number of slashes in the path, I'd be eternally grateful!

Comment: Wonderful, I got what I needed, many thanks. It is great, to add in the documentation ... cause I think is much important for seo reasons of course.